# Vagrant/Virtual Box vm only works if Virtual Box GUI is open

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

Vagrant version 2.3.7 and Virtual Box 7 and Windows 10 Host. I'm trying to vagrant up the machine with Ubuntu/focal64 box, powering it off for the first time it, but it just doesn't work. It gets hanging at `default: SSH auth method: password`, I changed the default login method, but it didn't work, in the GUI shown by Vagrant the Boot Up of the vm gets hanging at `xor: measuring software checksum speed`. The machine only ever continues to boot up after I open the virtual box GUI when everything magically starts working again. Does someone know what's going on? I'd really appreciate any insight.

Comment: I managed to get it working, although I didn't like the solution, just make the vm work with 1 CPU, and it works just fine.